# Nested Javascript async/await not being fired - Nuxt & Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I'm writing a basic middleware for NuxtJS 3 for authentication using Firebase and just need some help with proper chaining and nesting syntax.  Here's my code:

```js
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { auth, db } from '~/plugins/firebase';

export default async function ({ redirect }) {
  await onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const documentRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);

      const getDocData = async () => {
        const docSnap = await getDoc(documentRef);

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        }
      };
    }
  });
}
```

Most of it works, but the `const getDocData...` isn't firing and of course it's because I'm not even calling it but I have tried for hours to come up with a clean solution and nothing seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the callback `async`, as follows:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    const documentRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(documentRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log('Document data:', docSnap.data());
    }
  }
});
```

---

Also note that you need to change `doc.data()` to `docSnap.data()`.